# Unable to retrieve git reference using git parameter plugin. I am getting the below error while creating the builds

Tags: jenkins

I am getting this error while creating builds. I have uninstalled Git parameter plugins. I have checked URL as well by which I am cloning the repo. Can someone suggest me what am I missing here.

```
The default value has been returned
No Git repository configured in  SCM configuration or plugin is configured wrong 
Options'Use repository' is set as: 'exapmle.git' 
Please check the configuration
```

Comment: Hi Ayush! Welcome :) Could you share your Jenkins set up? Formatted code is generally preferred, or a screenshot otherwise.

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.263.4. Git parameter version is 0.9.13.


pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH', useRepository: 'https://example.git'        
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo "${params.BRANCH}"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: I am not able to see the branch and tags list. It is taking only default value. It is working for older jobs. If  I am adding any new job then I am seeing this issue.

Comment: This problem is purely on the Jenkins side. Fix that first before you worry about any Git issues. In particular the `useRepository` option is set wrong, as that's what Jenkins is complaining about here.

Comment: @torek As i mentioned in the above  comment that same repository is working fine with the existing JOB. If i am creating any new job and configured the same repository then I am facing the issue.  So if I am creating any new job I am seeing this error. I did not change any configuration or anything. I am not able to figure it out what's the issue here.

Comment: The error message you quoted is `Options'Use repository' is set as: 'exapmle.git'`. Presumably this needs to be a URL, not `exapmle.git`. Oddly, the text you quoted in a comment was `useRepository: 'http://example.git'`, which is a bit different but is still clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue and solved it by removing the `useRepository` option entirely. As described in the docs https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/ there is no need to set the option in single repo pipelines because:

> This plugin will read GIT SCM configuration from your project.

See https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/#plugin-content-error-handling

> This error occur when the repository is not configured or 'Use repository' option not match with any repository.

Answer (score 1):

1. need to set defaultBranch to master. Refer to ->> https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin/blob/master/README.md
2. Build the default branch first.
3. After that it will show all branches in the list [image].

This is because you have to clone for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue now on 2.361.1 - I used Jenkinsfile with the git parameter. When I started the build, it asked me for the parameter, but did not load any options.

It did it even after I duplicated another Jenkinsfile which worked. Then I noticed small note under the Jenkinsfile window - I disabled the Groovy sandbox and the note asked me to approve the script.

After the approval it started working; The current note is `The script is already approved`.